# Display table without refreshing the page on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django

I am working on a django application which displays a csv file as a table in the web application on file upload. This works properly but the problem is the page reloads when the form is submitted. For this purpose I tried using ajax to load the data without page refresh. But the code does not seem to work.

This is my code so far

### html

```
<form action="{% url 'csv_upload' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mt-2 mb-2 csv_upload_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile"/>
    <label for="file" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block select">Choose .csv file</label>
    <input class='btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block upload_csv_button' type="submit" value="Upload file" disabled/>
</form>
```

### javascript

```
$(document).on('submit', '.csv_upload_form', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  csvUploadAjax();
});

function csvUploadAjax() {
    let $form = $(".csv_upload_form");
    let form_data = new FormData($form[0]);
    console.log(form_data)
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            displayTable(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log("Something went wrong: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

function displayTable(data) {
  console.log(data)
  $(".scroll_it").val(data);
}
```

### The error

```
Something went wrong: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Major+Mono+Display|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- base.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css">

        <title>Home</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/index.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class='mt-5 title'>Dashboard</h1>
    <!-- <button class='btn btn-warning btn-lg start'>Start</button> -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-5">
            <div class="card-body upload_form">
                <form action="/csv_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mt-2 mb-2 csv_upload_form">
                    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='3J59IqYwIAdIRUf0V9gceqZ7ZoUomkLAGxsTGxXZ57j8m2a3vVsVpWznTu6jfEO2' />
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile"/>
                    <label for="file" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block select">Choose .csv file</label>
                    <input class='btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block upload_csv_button' type="submit" value="Upload file" disabled/>

              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="scroll_it">
        <table border="1" class="dataframe table table-bordered table-hover thead-dark">
```

In the above code, the error part of the code runs every-time. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am new to ajax and dont completely understand the code.

Please help me

Thank you

**[EDIT 1]**
I mistakenly commented out the console.log in the error part of the code. I removed the comment. And I also added the error message. It prints "something is wrong" and the html. I did not add the entire html as it is very big.

Comment: What are you seeing as part of the network calls? Is it directed at the correct url? Could it be a CORS issue?

Comment: Please add the error you are always getting as you said. error function looks like this ```Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )``` Please check and post what do you see in **textStatus** and **errorThrown**.

Comment: Can you check the **errorThrown** part of the response, that is where we can see the actual error.

Comment: the javascript itself does not throw any error. Only the `error: function (xhr) {
            console.log("Something went wrong: " + xhr.responseText);
        }` runs everytime

Comment: did the **success** code also execute or only the error one? @Sashaank

Comment: only the error part is executing everytime

Comment: Then there is a problem with request completion for sure. Please write the error function as 
```
error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong: " + err);
        }
```
And tell me what does it log in the console?

Comment: this is the output of the new code `Something went wrong: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`

Comment: You see there is an error in the JSON data you are sending. Now debug your **form_data** and make sure it is in correct JSON format. If you think the JSON is correct and you have tested it. We'll see what's wrong then.

Comment: I changed the dataType from `json` to `html`. now the `displayTable`  function runs. But I am not able to display the table. please help me with that

Comment: @Sashaank, understand that I can only do limited things from reading small part of your code. The fact table is not rendering could have any reason. Please find the bug yourself, I'll help you to fix it. You have to learn to debug eventually.

Comment: ok sure. I will do that